# C++11: How is object deleted if it was constructed using make_shared

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, reference-counting, weak-ptr

I am missing something about shared/weak pointers:

When a `shared_ptr` is constructed using `make_shared`, only one memory allocation is used (to allocate memory for control block and object itself). What happens when last `shared_ptr` is destroyed but there are `weak_ptr`-s left? At this point managed object has to be deallocated. But if memory allocated by `make_shared` gets deallocated, that would make weak pointers invalid, since same deallocation would destroy control block.

Comment: 20.7.2.2.6/6: "Remarks: Implementations are encouraged, *but not required*, to perform no more than one memory
allocation."  (Emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `make_shared` and `allocate_shared`, there's only one single reference control block that contains the object itself. It looks something like this:

```
struct internal_memory_type
{
    unsigned char[sizeof T] buf;   // make sure the object is at the top for
                                   // efficient dereferencing!
    // book keeping data
} internal_memory;
```

The object is constucted in-place: `::new (internal_memory.buf) T(args...)`.

Memory for the entire block is allocated with `::operator new`, or in case of `allocate_shared` with the allocator's `allocate()` function.

When the object is no longer needed, the destructor is called on the object itself, some thing like `internal_memory.buf->~T();`. When the reference control block is no longer needed, i.e. when all the weak references have disappeared as well as all the strong ones, the reference control block as a whole is freed with `::operator delete`, or with the allocator's `deallocate()` function for `allocate_shared`.

Comment: So when shared pointer count goes to zero, object memory may not be immediately freed, only destructor is called?

Comment: @user2052436: Naturally :-)

Comment: one more question: this means if there is a cycle of weak pointers, the memory will be consumed during entire program life, even if there are no shared pointers left?

Comment: @user2052436: Interesting! I don't think weak pointers can form cycles: Even if you assign one weak pointer to another one, you'd just end up with both of them observing the original shared pointer. Once both are destroyed, the shared pointer has two fewer weak observers.

Comment: @user2052436 Suppose we have a loop of `struct node { std::weak_ptr<node> next; };` with the elements kept alive by `shared_ptr<node>` to each one.  You then `.reset()` one `shared_ptr<node>`.  The `node` is destroyed but not deallocated: the `next` weak pointer's count goes down by one.  If you then `.reset()` the last `shared_ptr<node>` that `next` once referred to, it is both destroyed *and* deallocated.  If you remove all of the `shared_ptr`, every `weak_ptr` is destroyed, and the memory is all freed, as there are no weak or strong pointers to any of it alive.

Comment: @user2052436: Thing is, A and B aren't keeping each other alive, because they only have weak pointers to each other.  Once all the shared pointers to A are gone, A -- and the weak_ptr it contains -- will be destroyed.

Comment: @KerrekSB Why not? Isn't it allowed that an object has a pointer to his own type and weak pointer is used to hold it? Than we can have object A containing a weak pointer to B, and B containing a weak pointer to A. And say there is a container of shared pointers, containing A and B. One that container is destroyed, we have a cycle of weak pointers

Comment: @user2052436: Think again what the problem of a cycle is: You have two smart pointers that *both* die, but they keep the resource alive. That can't happen with weak pointers. When all the weak pointers die, the resource *does* die as well. The weak pointers don't observe each other, but the common shared pointer.

Comment: @KerrekSB Got it now: i forgot that destructor of A will reduce weak pointer count for B.